# JWT token is not set/stored in cookies after deploying to Vercel using MERN approach

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, jwt, vercel

I tried to look around for the solution everywhere but seems like no luck.

I am using React with Express and MongoDB atlast, I have deployed the application, however, the issue is I can see that the JWT token is issued and I can see that is stored in set-cookies headers but not in cookies storage (Developer tool) and also not verified.

I have tried it using localhost it does work as expected but not working when I deployed.

Please see the code below:
Vercel Screenshot:

[image]

Error From Developer Tool.

[image]

[image]

**Index.js**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const app = express();
//const configs = require("./config.js");

dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
require("./db/connection");
//const config = configs[process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"];

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Use CORS middleware to allow requests from specific origins
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "https://frontEnd.vercel.app", // Replace with your frontend URL
        methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
        credentials: true, // Enable cookies and credentials to pass through the request
    })
);

app.use(require("./router/route"));

//Middleware
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    next();
};
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**route.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const router = express.Router();

require("../db/connection");
const User = require("../model/newUserSchema");
const Auth = require("../middleware/auth");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello am backend sever");
});

//Signup or  Register Part
router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, cpassword, retypePassword } = req.body;

    if (!username || !email || !cpassword || !retypePassword) {
        return res.status(422).json({ error: "please enter valid details" });
    }

    try {
        const UserExist = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (UserExist) {
            return res.status(422).json({ error: "email already exist" });
        } else if (cpassword !== retypePassword) {
            return res.status(422).json({ error: "password incorrect" });
        } else {
            const user = new User({
                username,
                email,
                cpassword,
                retypePassword,
            });

            const userResgister = await user.save();

            if (userResgister) {
                return res.status(201).json({ message: "signup successfully" });
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

//Login Part
router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, cpassword } = req.body;

        if (!email || !cpassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: " please enter valid credentials" });
        }

        const userLogin = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (userLogin) {
            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(cpassword, userLogin.cpassword);

            const token = await userLogin.generateAuthToken();
            console.log("JWT token ", token);
            // Setting a cookie with the correct domain and path
            // res.cookie("signinToken", token, {
            //     domain: "https://backend-api.vercel.app", // Set the domain to match both frontend and backend
            //     path: "/signin", // Set the path to the route where the cookie is used
            //     expires: new Date(Date.now() + 25892000000),
            //     httpOnly: true,
            // });

            res.cookie("signinToken", token, {
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 25892000000),
                httpOnly: true,
            });

            if (isMatch) {
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "sigin in scuccessfully" });
            } else {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: " Invalid credentials" });
            }
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "  Invalid credentials " });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

//Watchlist  Part where I want to verify user with JWT
router.get("/watchlist", Auth, (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.rootuser);
});

//Signout  Part
router.get("/signout", (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie("signinToken", { path: "/" });
    res.status(200).send("signed out");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Auth.js which is where I am verifing the user with JWT**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../model/newUserSchema");

const SECRETKEY = "myScretKeyyyyyyyyyyyyeeee";

const Auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.signinToken;
        if (!token) {
            console.log("no token found");
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
        const verifytoken = jwt.verify(token, SECRETKEY);

        const rootuser = await User.findOne({ _id: verifytoken._id, "tokens.token": token });

        if (!rootuser) {
            throw new Error("user not found");
        }

        req.token = token;
        req.rootuser = rootuser;
        req.UserID = rootuser._id;

        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send("Unauthorized access: token not found");
        console.log(error);
    }
};

module.exports = Auth;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the local storage to handle the user data and token by creating a function in the client folder:

```
export default function useUserSession(){
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    const saveToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
    const [userData, setData]=useState({
        username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
        id: localStorage.getItem('id')
    })
    const [userToken, setToken]=useState(saveToken);

    function logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        setToken(null);
        navigate('/');
    }

    function saveUserSession(token, callback){
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        setToken(token, callback);
    }

    function saveUserData(username, id){
        localStorage.setItem('username', username);
        localStorage.setItem('id', id);
        setData({username: username, id: id});
    }

    return {
        token: userToken,
        username: userData.username,
        id: userData.id,
        saveUserSession,
        saveUserData,
        logout
    }
}
```

Then, in your frontend where you handle login invoke the save functions to store data you need like so:
`const {saveUserSession, saveUserData}=useUserSession();`

and use it to save those data, for example:

```
const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('your-endpoint', user-credentials)
        .then(res=>{
            saveUserSession(res.data.token);
            saveUserData(res.data.username, res.data.id);
        })
        .then(err=>console.log(err));
    }
```

To use the stored value just create:
`const {token, username, logout}=useUserSession();`
and type the necessary value where needed.

Hope i could help.